# Similar diodes in bridge rectification

Tags: semiconductor-physics

**Why are similar kinds of diodes used in bridge rectification ? What will be the problem if different kinds of diodes are used ?**

> My book says that , the oscillation of current through circuit would be different . But I can't understand the effect of it .

Comment: Well, each one would have different I-V characteristics, so the legs of the bridge would not behave the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason similar (matched) diodes should be used, is so that the current passing through each diode matches the current on its "complementary" diode.  This provides a "purer" DC current as the AC components cancel-out.
If the AC components do not cancel-out, this causes a "signal" called ripple.  The more unmatched the diodes, the larger the amplitude of the ripple. This ripple "rides" on top of the DC, and is considered electrical noise - which is something you do not want in electronic systems.